# CakePHP 2.1.0: Capture E-mail Output

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm building a CakePHP website that sends an e-mail like this:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
$email->template('test');
$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->to(array('john_doe@example.com' => 'John Doe'));
$email->subject('Test E-mail');
$email->helpers(array('Html', 'Text'));
$email->viewVars(
    array(
        ...
    )
);

if ($email->send()) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('The e-mail was sent!', 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
}
else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('An unexpected error occurred while sending the e-mail.', 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-error'));
}
```

I'd like to be able to capture the HTML rendered by the e-mail in a variable in addition to actually sending the e-mail. This way, I can record in the database the exact content of the e-mail's body. Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [line 50 of the `MailTransport` class](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/mail-transport), it appears the actual `send()` function returns the message and the header.  So instead of:

```
if($email->send()) {
```

Try:

```
$mySend = $email->send();
if($mySend) {
    //...
```

Then, `$mySend` should be an array:

```
array('headers' => $headers, 'message' => $message);
```

Comment: Did you get an error?  What about it didn't work?  (I changed from $this->email->message() to just $email->message() )

Comment: (Edited answer to something I think should work - if it does, I'll remove the first portion of my answer)

Comment: i have implement mail function in local server. i cant send mail in local but is there any chances that i can see that mail without sending it in local

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I do in my EmailLib:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Lib/EmailLib.php

it logs email attempts and captures the email output into a log file (`email_trace.log`) in `/tmp/logs/` - if you are in debug mode it will only log (no emails sent - this has been proven quite useful for local delopment).

you can write a similar wrapper for your case.
but if you want to write it back into the DB Dave's approach seems to fit better.